# How to select multiple columns from a table while ensuring that one specific column doesn't contain duplicate values in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Table:**

```
x_id---y---z_id------a-------b-------c
1------0----NULL----Blah----Blah---Blah
2------0----NULL----Blah----Blah---Blah
3------10---6-------Blah----Blah---Blah
3------10---5-------Blah----Blah---Blah
3------10---4-------Blah----Blah---Blah
3------10---3-------Blah----Blah---Blah
3------10---2-------Blah----Blah---Blah
3------10---1-------Blah----Blah---Blah
4------0----NULL----Blah----Blah---Blah
5------0----NULL----Blah----Blah---Blah
```

**My Query**:

```
SELECT
    #temp.x_id,
    #temp.y,
    MAX(#temp.z_id) AS z_id
FROM #temp
GROUP BY 
    #temp.x_id
```

**Error**:
`Column 'y' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

**Requirement:**
I want x_id to be unique and i want to select the MAX value of z_id

**Expected Output:**

```
x_id---y---z_id------a-------b-------c
1------0----NULL---Blah----Blah-----Blah
2------0----NULL---Blah----Blah-----Blah
3------10---6------Blah----Blah-----Blah
4------0----NULL---Blah----Blah-----Blah
5------0----NULL---Blah----Blah-----Blah
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are seeing is a common one, and it is happening because when you state `GROUP BY x_id` you are telling SQL Server to return a single record for every value of `x_id`.  However, when you select `y`, it is unclear as to *which* one of possibly many values you want to use.  Hence, it is resulting in error.  One correct approach would be to use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES x_id, y, z_id, a, b, c
FROM #temp
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x_id ORDER BY z_id DESC);
```